# Is there a throttle in place for account creations or can I create accounts at 50k tps?

Tags: account, tps

Other networks have throttles, I noticed there is a minimum balance on Solana, so does that mean as long as I have enough SOL I can create accounts at a rate of 50k tps? @ripatel

Answer (score 1):

Yep! That's the whole point of tools like `solana-bench-tps`, where it sees just how many transactions it can push through the network: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/bench-tps

You can follow along with tests that try to do as many transactions as possible in parallel. The Solana Tech Discord https://discord.gg/5yJFjszY has multiple channels that report results, such as `#bench-tps-dos-results` and `#mango-bench-tps-dos`.

In your tests, if you're creating all of your accounts from one account, you'll be limited by the write throughput on that one account. Since all of the creation transactions will take a write lock on the source account, they cannot be parallelized by the runtime, so you will get nowhere near 50k TPS.